# Why Some FontAwesom Icons are not loaded after deploying to heroku?

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

I am working on a React project and I have used fontAwesom icons in it. all the icons ware visible when using it on localhost. but now I have deployed it to heroku.com Now some of the icons are not visible to me.

I noticed Icons whose name starts with **fa fa** are visible but Icons name starting with **fab** or any other are not visible. even I have included the script link of both icons list. and they are working perfectly fine on localhost server.

after deploying I am getting following error on console for not getting those Icons

`Access to script at 'https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js' from origin 'https://tajarat.herokuapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: #1 Could you share us your package.json? #2 Could you test the build in your localhost instead the developer mode?

Comment: The error clearly says there is CORS issue from source (https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js) to destination (https://tajarat.herokuapp.com). Is it possible to remove url reference to fontawesome and install npm package and check. Then all the scripts will be loaded from your website url in browser

Answer (score 0):

It's an CORS issue. You may use fontawesome URL from [CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome).